# High Temperature when stress testing Intel Core i7 3770K

Tags: gpu, temperature, intel-core-i7, cpu-cooler

I have bought an i7 3770K.  I have tried to stress it, N

ear full load computation using CUDA I was surprised that it gets 99°C at 68% of the CPU load, is this normal? I have to change the cooling system?

I use a Cooler Master Hyper TX3 cooling (that is for i5 maybe). Should I use the normal fan sold with the CPU?

On Idle my CPU too is in the gap 32°-38° C the problem is under stress (only 68%) and I'm not overclocking the system!

The problem could be due to the GPU? But I have checked and I don't think so.

Comment: *> i7 3770K High Temperature*   Wow, you *really* have a problem if your system is over 3,496°C. `:-P`

Comment: Yes that is way too high. The TJMAX for i7's is 100 degrees. What you should do is stop your computer immediately and re-seat your cooler with new thermal paste, you have most likely just put the paste incorrectly.

Comment: is it a laptop?

Comment: "I have tried to stress it" : Done! ;-)

Comment: @AlanTuring The TJMAX is 105 degrees for the Ivy Bridge i7's. These temperatures are normal, and I honestly wouldn't be worried about them. http://www.overclockers.com/ivy-bridge-temperatures

Comment: @Huskehn at 68% load, this actually isn't normal at all.

Comment: @Huskehn i'm pretty sure 99 degrees at any point is pretty bad in general and is not wanted at all. how can you say that it is normal lol.  But yea sorry about that misinformation, it seems intel upped it for the new generation.

Comment: Where are you guys getting this info from? Intel states the Tcase is 67.4 for that processor, there is no way that the thermal juction and tcase have 40 degree difference... it's impossible. 105 is the tjmax for the mobile Ivy bridge. Check the specs for the desktop processor: http://ark.intel.com/products/65523/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz

Comment: I'd be concerned with anything over 70c on that processor with no OC, with OC 80.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to check a few things to see if this is causing the High CPU Temperatures.

1. Make sure that you used Thermal Paste
2. Don't use too much. A drop or two is sufficient. A paper thin spread is ideal.
3. Clean any excess paste around CPU and Heatsink with Qtip and Denatured Alcohol. If you have paste that is overflowing, the heat cannot dissipate properly.
4. Make sure that you have a solid connection with the heatsink.
5. Make sure that the heatsink is receiving proper ventilation. (free of dust bunnies)

I have the Coolermaster N520 on my Ivy Bridge Core i7 and idle it will run about 32c.

[image]

I needed to do a small video compression today and took a snapshot of the CPU load and CPU temperature. With a large CPU load, it still was about 35c-37c.

[image]

Comment: Asus Aisuite monitors Tcase not core temperature... Check any other monitoring software the core temperatures won't match what that sensor is telling you. Your core temps are probably close to 50. You're comparing apples to oranges here...

Comment: Not trying to give you a hard time. You should actually  be monitoring the tcase not tjunction since intel only releases specifications for tcase on desktop CPU's. Also core temps are incredibly unreliable: http://superuser.com/questions/477159/laptop-overheats-bsod-turns-off-when-playing-games/477179#477179

Comment: What are you monitoring with this program?
I have 5 different temperature for my i7, (lmsensors)
 1 for each core and 1 for physical id...
And temp1 and temp2 for the motherboard that are
always 28° and 30°....

Comment: How you could cool an i7 3th gen with that cooler that do not support the 1155 socket?? Are you joking?? (Ah, ok, maybe beacuse it's back compatible)

Comment: It definitely works with the hardware provided in the box. No fabrication needed.