# FPS dropping in several game despite formated hard drive

Tags: graphics, fps

I have a big problem with fps-drop when playing different games. 
Ex. CS 1.6, having 100fps drops down to 30-50, same problem in games like LoL and WOW, tho I drop down to 7-10 in WOW... 
I have formated my hard drive and downloaded the latest drivers. 
Since I've always had settled FPS before I don't know why and how to fix this.
Using a 1 year old laptop,  MSI gt70 with Nvidia GTX 570M.

Edit: Checked the temp. CPU: max 98°C (208°F) GPU: max 68°C (154°F)

Comment: does it heat up considerably? when have you had it clean up for the last time?

Comment: @Znau CPU: max 98°C (208°F) GPU: max 68°C (154°F). Don't think I've ever cleaned it..

Comment: it seems to me your machine needs proper cleaning and thermal paste replacement. 98ºC for your CPU is WAY too much.

Comment: 98C is really high. If you have been running it overtime at those temps I would not be surprised if it has begun to degrade. My suggestion would be to download a utility that can monitor thermal throttling rather than raw temperature. If the TJ max isn't calibrated properly your temps will not be accurate. http://superuser.com/questions/477159/laptop-overheats-bsod-turns-off-when-playing-games/477179#477179

Answer (score 2):

First, what OS are you running? Also, what are your temperatures while you're in a game? You can use Coretemp and Rivatuner to check.

Your hard drive likely has nothing to do with it. I'm betting your laptop is clogged with dust and hair, causing inefficient cooling. Open it up, carefully clean out the vents, reapply thermal paste as needed, and you'll be good to go!

Edit: it could also be possible that one of your fans died, but more than likely it's dust.

Comment: Used HWmonitor. 
CPU: max 98°C (208°F)
GPU: max 68°C (154°F)
too much I guess?

Comment: And theeere's your problem! Depending on your CPU, it should never go past 60-75 deg. C. Turn it off, open it up (make sure you have the manual handy), clean it out, and reapply the thermal paste if disassembly requires you to remove any heatsinks. If you aren't comfortable this, you can try giving some sharp blows INTO the vents from the outside, which will buy you some time until you can have a techie friend help you out.

Comment: thank you very much, I just blowed into the vents and it worked! Waiting for my friend to clean it up now. 
Again, thank you.

Comment: After blowing, make sure your temps have dropped to more reasonable levels. Running close to 100 deg. C for an extended time is dangerous, you could fry your CPU.