# VAIO Laptop overheat

Tags: laptop, overheating

I have a [VPCF111FX](http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=VPCF111FX&template_id=1&region_id=1&tab=howto#/howtoTab) VAIO laptop. Since I first bought it, even during low CPU usage, very hot air is blowing from its fan.  The fan is also very noisy.

Sony published some BIOS update for it, and I installed it but it was not effective.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Hot wind blowing means that the fan is doing its job. A noisy fan can mean many things. Anyway, what is your question? What do you want solved?

Comment: Have you actually monitored any temperatures?  For example, does Speedfan http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php work for you to enable you to see actual idle and load temps?  As @Xavierjazz points out, hot air from the exhaust port means the cooling fan is working properly, as it is supposed to draw in cool air, push it through a hot heat sink and push out hot air.

Comment: @BonGart I installed it, It show two fan: CPU fan and fan2, CPU fan is almost 5160RPM (CPU temp is 73c and usage ~10%) and Fan2 is 0RPM. Is Fan2 a real fan? Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: No.  It is quite common for Speedfan to show more than one fan or temperature output that produces a false reading.  Speedfan is a generic program written to interpret the outputs of hundreds of different motherboards.  That motherboard might have had a second fan when used in a different model VAIO, or it might have been a Just-In-Case move on the part of the engineers who designed the motherboard.  In any case, the fan appears to be working **quite** well.  Your temp, however, does appear to be quite warm.  When was the last time the laptop was taken apart and cleaned?

Comment: @BonGart I never take it apart. I bought it two years ago.

Comment: @phpst If speedfan is reporting 73C that means it is actually at 82C which is getting close to thermal shutdown. Remember these programs that measure core temp are calibrated to a tjmax of 91c while that processor's tjmax is 100C. http://superuser.com/questions/477159/laptop-overheats-bsod-turns-off-when-playing-games/477179#477179

Comment: Be aware that Sony had a problem with the fan on some "VGN" models and offered to do [extended warranty repairs](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/news-item.pl?news_id=299&mdl=VGNCS290J) on them.  You may want to search Sony's web site for something similar for your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You laptop is properly got too much dust in the cooler.

1st purchase some thermal paste (Cooling paste...).

2nd, dissemble you laptop I think yours is also unibody like my Vaio, it's easy to dissemble it.

3rd, take out the fan and the cooler, rust off the dust from the cooler you should use a vacuum cleaner to clean it.

4th, scrape off the old thermal paste from the cooler, cpu and the chipset - graphics card with a credit card and rust of by apply some isopropyl alcohol, after that apply thermal paste to your cpu and chipset.

5th, install your fan and cooler then resemble your laptop. Check your fan is working properly or not.

Comment: NO!  Bad user.  Do not "scratch" off the old thermal paste.  You should use 5% rubbing (isopropyl) alcohol to clean the cooler.  Do not use any abrasives or scratching tools.

Comment: Why? The old thermal paste should be replaced otherwise the conduction will not work well.

Comment: Yes, it should be removed, but you shouldn't scratch it off.  Scraping would work, but you should really just wet a lint-free cloth with the alcohol and wipe the paste off.

Comment: @Kruug, Nam Phung actually said "scratch with a credit card" (it is clearer after my edit) so I doubt he meant _scratch_. The subtle difference between _scrape_ and _scratch_ will not be obvious to a non-native speaker

Comment: Thanks Nam. It was all about dust! I cleaned it and replaced its thermal pasts.

Answer (score 2):

Go purchase a can of compressed air.  Blow out all vent openings on the laptop.

After that, re-run SpeedFan and monitor the information that it is given both during idle times as well as times when you have it under normal use.

If the temperature/fan speed is lowered, then great!

Also, make sure that you have clear areas around the laptop during use.  Do not set it on anything fabric (chair, couch, bed, carpet, etc) as this will block the airflow to the vital parts of the laptop.

Hot air from the fan is (generally) normal. A noisy fan may need to be replaced as it may end up just not working one day.

Comment: For "clear areas around the laptop" also add the bottom. Propping-up the rear of the laptop so air can circulate below can help a lot (but of course only if vents are clear).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the clearing out your air vents, consider buying a cooling pad. Most computer stores offer them for around $20-$30, and they're usually just a plastic or metal pad with a USB-powered fan that blows air upward onto the base of the laptop. It serves the dual purpose of giving your laptop more room to breathe, and cooling it off. And as a bonus, you can use the laptop without burning your legs!

If online shopping is more your thing, both [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=2243862011) and [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Laptop-Accessories/SubCategory/ID-319) have a decent selection.

Answer (score 1):

When I check the specs of your laptop, I see that you do have a fairly powerful processor, but when the laptop is idle, it should actually consume very little power. I assume that you have Windows 7 installed? Try setting the power plan to "Balanced" or "Power saver" and see if that makes a difference. Also, if you have previously played around with that, try resetting the power plan settings to the defaults.

Another thing would be to check the BIOS for energy-related settings, you should enable "sleep states", especially "C6" and "C1E", and maybe you'll find some other options like EIST.

To check these power-saving features, you can use a program like [ThrottleStop](http://www.techinferno.com/downloads/).

Finally (though not likely since you say it had been so right from the start), you may have a virus which keeps you computer busy, so try booting from an Anti-Virus CD or USB memory stick.

Answer (score -1):

What material is the case made of? If it is aluminum or even and copper-like, then the odds are most likely that it will heat up but mainly that means that it's good, because the CPU or processors mostly have a heat sink on them.

Comment: Its case is made of plastic.