# Graphics freeze whenever hard drive is accessed

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, nvidia-geforce, lag

Any time I'm playing a game (and even sometimes just using desktop programs), whenever the game accesses the hard drive the graphics freeze. Sometimes the audio stutters, most other times it doesn't.

I cannot figure out what's wrong. The games will run fine for a few seconds, but whenever something loads (i.e. I look at something new), the game will freeze for a few moments and then resume at full-force.

This happens at any point with any game, and is not your regular lag. Some games do so whenever a new model is loaded (or, for instance, when a block is broken in minecraft).

How can I go about debugging this issue?

The laptop isn't that old, and has done this ever since it was purchased. I was using the updated drivers for a while, and then tried the beta drivers with no luck. No overclocking is being done.

Specs:

- Alienware M17xr3
- Windows 7 64-bit
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560M
- Intel Core i7-2670QM 2.20 GHz
- 8 GB Ram

The laptop is an Alienware, <strike>so the model number is, of course, nowhere to be seen on the bottom.</strike> Model number added to specs.

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, here are the temps during both idle and gaming sessions. It should be noted that **whenever the freeze occurs, the GPU usage drops to 0.**

CPU Min/Max [core 1,2,3,4] : GPU
(*All are in degrees Celsius*)

- Idle: 56/61, 60/68, 58/69, 52/61 : 62
- Game 1: 63/76, 66/83, 66/83, 62/81 : 66
- Game 2: 56/79, 61/85, 58/84, 54/81 : 66-67

Something else I should add is that the CPU power drops from around 32 watts to less than 15 (often times down to 7) whenever the freeze occurs - however, the programmer in me thinks that it's a side effect of the program itself due to the freeze and not being able to query the CPU.

Another note is that background music plays without interruption during these freezes; the CPU is still doing *something* when it freezes. Some of the game's sound effects will loop, but not in a soundcard freeze way.

Comment: What operating system (be as specific as possible)? How much RAM? Have you changed any OS settings, particularly relating to memory management or power management?

Comment: Your laptop has dual graphics card. Have you tried setting it to run on NVIDIA graphics only?

Comment: Can you install and run two programs (I do not care which specific ones); on to monitor CPU temperature, one to monitor the graphics chips temperature. Write down the values when the laptop is idle and when you are gaming (displaying them on a second screen while playing a full screen game is usually the easiest way). But before you do that check the event log messages. Any errors in there? For instance 'Thermal event' messages. Or 'disk read errors', esp. if the disk is set to older IO modes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Specs added. Nothing changed recently, other than a reformat; this issue has been around since its purchase. Reformatting neither fixes nor causes the issue.

Comment: @gronostaj - No indication it has a dual graphics card. Is there somewhere specific in the nVidia control panel that would say it does?

Comment: @Hennes - No errors whatsoever that are related to the thermals or disk - the last few errors occurred two days ago. I'll take some temps here in a second.

Comment: @Hennes - Temps added. I'll do a few more games; some do it more than others. For now, that should give a good idea. The thing I did notice on the monitors was that GPU usage dropped to 0% whenever there was a freeze.

Comment: @Qix i7s have built-in Intel GPU and usually laptops use that one for power saving and NVIDIA GPU for gaming (this is called NVIDIA Optimus). Optimus laptops have Intel graphics driver installed and all color and display settings are in Intel's panel. NVIDIA panel has an option to switch between GPUs.

Comment: @gronostaj I don't see it anywhere. Is it under a certain name or term?

Comment: @Qix If you have Nvidia optimus you will be able to set the primary video adapter from the main page in the Nvidia control panel, so check if there is a drop down box.

Comment: Two other things to check: 1. use resource monitor to look at the disk, ignore transfer and watch the disk queue, see if it jumps when you notice the processor enter a lower P state or even C0 (idle). The drop in power usage may be due to throttling from high temperatures. Unless you manually calibrated the TJmax in your thermal monitoring program for that CPU I would bet the readings you got are off by 10-20C. Most programs are calibrated for a Thermal junction max of 91C while all mobile I series chips I have seen have TJmax closer to 100-110.

Comment: If you want further info on temperature readings for Intel chips  check my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/477159/laptop-overheats-bsod-turns-off-when-playing-games/477179#477179

Comment: @Kyle I can't. I hit the button to switch adapters and it tells me it's done "automatically".

Comment: Is your laptop fully patched, including optional Windows Update ?

Comment: @harrymc - Yes.

Comment: @Qix what do you mean by button? there should be a drop down (list box) in the nvidia control panel for preferred graphic adapter.

Comment: @Kyle there isn't any drop down at all (trust me, I've checked quite a few times). I hit the Fn key combo that usually switches the adapters.

Comment: @Qix not sure when the m17xR3 was released but my M11xR2 had terrible issues with the non dell provided drivers using optimus. All the hacking I did was useless. The fact you are missing the drop down makes me wonder if you used the nvidia drivers? I did that a few times either by mistake (windows update) or while trying to get a game to run and it never worked out well at all.

Comment: @Qix that drop down also only shows in the advanced view. I know you said you checked but I feel like I should mention it anyway since it will default to the simple view.

Comment: @Kyle It is [literally](http://i.imgur.com/uoP5CCa.png) [not](http://i.imgur.com/c5REBKN.png) [anywhere](http://i.imgur.com/qynk6xu.png) [to](http://i.imgur.com/0qS4aIb.png) [be](http://i.imgur.com/53xFid2.png) [found](http://i.imgur.com/ebnaGlA.png). There is no advanced view.

Comment: `The fact you are missing the drop down makes me wonder if you used the nvidia drivers` If you mean the ones I got off of the nVidia support/driver download website, yes, those are the ones I am using.

Comment: @Qix The option is under the tree "manage 3d settings" and yes I meant the drivers from the nvidia site. It's worth trying the dell drivers. Again, I was never able to get the official Nvidia drivers working with my alienware.

Comment: @Kyle - Upgraded the VBIOS and disabled turbo CPU while I was at it; the freezes are less frequent, but still there. I will download and install the dell drivers here in a sec.

Comment: @qix  Without knowing the exact model of I7 and the TJmax of your processor those temps in the 80'sC could easily be in the 90's/100'sC (thermal throttling territory). Every mobile I series chip I have ever looked up the tjmax on has it much higher than the default of 91 (up to 110c). This could mean your temps could be off by as much as 20C. As a side note: updating the bios most likely updated the cooling profile and turning off turbo boost would significantly decrease temperatures. Interesting that this helps... I would not count overheating out yet.

Comment: @Kyle - Added exact i7 model.

Comment: @qix tjmax is 100 on that processor. Assuming you didn't calibrate your thermal monitoring program: the highest core reading (85) on the Digital thermal sensor was 6. Adjusting for our now known TJ max: thermal junction max - DTS = 94 that is definitely throttling territory. between the readings, the wattage drop, and performance increase after disabling turbo. It's pretty safe to say your CPU is overheating.

Comment: You can see this yourself with the resource monitor or Intel Extreme tuning utility.

Comment: I would believe it; the games worked great for a little bit but over time (assuming when the CPU heated up) they started to glitch out again.

Comment: Thing is I already blew out all of the dust, and it's sitting on top of a heating pad. Not sure what else I could do to help it.

Comment: Intel Extreme reports no throttling whatsoever, even **during** a freeze; although that really doesn't surprise me. It's probably incorrect.

Comment: Just for kicks, I downloaded speedfan (I turned off the cooling pad and could hardly find the fans they were so quiet). It doesn't allow me to change any fan speeds at all, which is annoying since the fans on the back don't even seem to be on.

Comment: AHA! HWINFO64 allows me to change the fan speeds. Perfect!

Comment: Nope, the problem is still there; arguably worse right now. Fans are keeping the temps *< 50C* at all times; even during a game. That's a plus, at least, but it still isn't the issue.

Answer (score 3):

My own suspicion is that this has a connection to the fact that your CPU model supports
an impressive automatic overclocking from 2.2 to 3.3 Ghz,
but that Windows 7 also supports [CPU core parking](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/03/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-core-parking-intelligent-timer-tick-timer-coalescing.aspx).
There might be some kind of a conflict between them going on in that souped-up Alienware model of yours.

You might be able to use the tool [TMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/tmonitor.html) (if it supports your CPU) to watch the power fluctuations as a complement to Resource Monitor.

To test my above theory, you might try to temporarily disable core parking, at least partially for a couple of cores.

Here is a very exhaustive article on the subject :
[Disable CPU Core Parking Real-Time - No Reboot](http://bitsum.com/about_cpu_core_parking.php).

This article links to the ParkControl free utility that
enables/disables CPU core parking for any given power profile
(and which I never tried).
There is also a discussion about how to do the same using PowerCfg.

I suggest to be very cautious and create a System Restore point before changing
these parameters and to mind your backups.
Before starting, the first step should be to use Windows Update to ensure that all your drivers are up to date.

If the test shows this as the cause (or if it doesn't),
you could contact the Support of Alienware for a solution.

Comment: Learned something new! Didn't know what core parking was. Unfortunately, this didn't help anything at all. Resource monitor also ruled out any sort of network blocking issue or anything of the like. The CPU did fall during the freezes, but core temp already showed that.

Comment: The way I see this, voltage drop means that the CPU (or GPU) started using more power and it took some time for the power supply to adjust. If the cause isn't the core parking, but for example the overclocking kicking-in, it might be that the power supply is too slow to react and the whole house of electrical cards falls down. There are really too many variables here to analyze. So I suggest again to get in touch with Alienware Support for probable causes and then to (1) use your warranty if you still have it, or (2) ask a technician to verify the PSU, motherboard and GPU.

Comment: What's weird is that I did a complete driver downgrade (to literally the lowest version I could get) and the issue went away. The debugger in me decided to go up one version to see if that fixed things; it brought the issue back, and when I downgraded again back to the lowest version, the issue was still there. I should have left it alone.

Bottom line is that the drivers did make a difference.

Comment: That's also a matter for Alienware Support.

Comment: I would try to determine which driver is at fault by dropping the system back to the lowest driver levels I could find. Then I'd upgrade one driver at a time until I determined which one it was.

Comment: I did that already; it worked for the lowest (and I was dumb and tried to upgrade), and when I did the issue came back. Then I tried down-grading again back to the lowest and the issue stayed around.

Comment: You might need to do a complete uninstall of the drivers, reboot and reinstall the drivers that work.

Comment: @harrymc - I've done that 3 or 4 times now to no avail. Some of the people at root access had me do that earlier.

Comment: Can you rollback to a system restore point dating from before you installed the bad drivers?

Comment: @harrymc They've always been bad drivers.

Comment: But you said that driver downgrade worked ... All you have to do is return to the time in which the downgrade was possible.

Comment: It seemed to have worked for 5 minutes before I upgraded.

Comment: Also, system restore doesn't report it'd change any graphics drivers. The most it would delete are two programs since the last restore point (since none of them are from before the driver installs, weirdly).

Comment: System restore returns the registry to an old state, which in effect replaces the drivers even if they are still physically present, and there is no way to know in advance what exactly it would do.

Answer (score 2):

Without further details about your laptop, I'd point my finger at:

1. A weak CPU that isn't up to the task.
2. Overheating (caused by dust accumulation or insufficient ventilation). Clean out your laptop vents with a can of compressed air. Use a [laptop cooling pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop_cooler) while gaming to keep temperatures down.
3. If your laptop has a dual/switchable GPU feature, there might be a driver incompatibility behind this.

Can you post your laptop specs (or model number)?

Comment: Added specs. It's definitely not the CPU, unless i7's are not up to the task ;)

Comment: Also added temps.

Comment: I've accounted for all three of these; nothing helps.

Answer (score 2):

i have a MX17r2 and it did the same thing till i updated the BIOS, reinstalled the graphics driver and reinstalled the updated Chipset drivers, Alienware's are VERY picky and complain a lot at every turn. If that doesnt work start from a fresh OS install and get all the drivers.

P.S. Ignore the alienware driver disk that came with it. Out dated drivers and for some odd reason they never work.

Comment: This was a new OS installation. I did flash the bios, but it was already at the newest (I flashed anyway). None of the chipset drivers pertained to anything relevant (all were for the tilt sensor and SD card and stuff). I've reinstalled the graphics driver several times now.

Comment: have you done a disk check to check for bad sectors on the drive?

Comment: i have also been doing some research on the 560 mobile version and it does not like certain drivers, its a very picky mobile card, you might have to consider upgrading the card (which is easy in Alienware) or you can revert to the old driver for the card and leave it that way until NVidea comes out with a more stable driver for this card.

Comment: yes I have tried disk checking; nothing came up. I may end up replacing the card or testing with a field replacement to see if it is, indeed, the card.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my tips:
- try to disconect every (USB) device connected to your notebook and run your game
- is your HDD in perfect condition? Download "crystal disk info" and check IDs 03, 05, C5, C6-all must have RAW value 0
- download "furmark" and run benchmark
- download "prime95" - run blend test (you can combine it with furmark burn-in test for maximal load)
**!!!Watch carefully for temperatures!!!**